# Why does VSCode say Python is not installed?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I open up my VSCode, I immediately get the message "Python is not installed. Please download and install Python before using the extension." in the bottom right.

When I close VSCode and open it up again, the error message is fixed and it says Python 3.10 in the bottom right. But why didn't it work in the first place?

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both Python and VSCode, but it still does this.
Is there anything else that I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the result of python --version in the terminal out of the VSCode?

Comment: The result is Python 3.10.3

Comment: You can try switching to the release version of python extension.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments. This might help

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Thanks for the feedback, which extension is the one you're refering to?

Comment: @Albert van Zyl As I said, an extension named "python", https://imgur.com/a/pqXnU5l

Comment: Mine doesn't say "Switch to release version", it says "Switch to pre-release version".

Comment: @Albert van Zyl You can also try pre-release version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused by python extension version.

You can try switching to pre-release version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the python path is added to your environment variables. Also did you install python separately, if you do then there is a small checkbox during installation that you need to tick to add python path to environment variables

Comment: This is not the answer. It's a comment.

Comment: @Phantoms What do you want to tell.

Comment: Yes, it is added to my environment variables and I did check the box during installation.

Comment: He can get the result of command "python --version". This is not the correct answer.