# VS Code not seeing python interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When trying to run code in Visual Studio Code, it says 'Please select an interpreter'. When I go to do that,  it says that python is not installed. [image: Error shown] When I try to run the same code through IDLE, it works perfectly.

I have tried selecting the "python.exe" file manually, via the "Enter interpreter path" button. When I do that, it just says "Invalid Interpreter".

I have also tried installing python via the Microsoft store, but when I do that, it breaks all of my libraries, even though it is the same version of python.

I have tried both the release, and pre-release version of the python extension.

I am using python 3.10.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does VSCode say Python is not installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72314164/why-does-vscode-say-python-is-not-installed)

Comment: @NelsonGon it does not, I have tried both, and edited my question to me more clear.

Comment: Don't just enter `python.exe` in the field; enter the **full path** to python.exe.  i.e. something like `C:\Programs\Python310\python.exe`

Comment: @JohnGordon I did.

Comment: @CozmoKitten can you run pyhton on Powershell?
You should get all accessible paths with the following command:
`get-command -all python`

Comment: If you're entering the full correct path, and VS Code complains that it is invalid, then I don't know what else to try.